# Cannot retrieve the key and Value info from the deserialized data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

```
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                foreach (var field in data)
                {
                    var deserializedData = new DeserializedData
                    {
                        Label = field.Key.ToObject<string>(),
                        Content = field.Value.ToObject<string>()
                    };
                }
```

Note:     data = {"name":"test"}
Error:'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

I think I understand what the issue is but I am not sure if there is a way to achieve this behavior or is there a different approach to handle the dynamic key value scenarios like this.
The Key will change so I don't know if its going to be name or phone or email or some other field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to iterate through the children of the returned `data` as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>`, you need to explicitly declare the deserialized object as a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm):

```
    var data = JObject.Parse(result);
    foreach (var field in data)
    {
        var deserializedData = new DeserializedData
        {
            Label = field.Key,
            Content = field.Value.ToObject<string>()
        };
    }
```

When you do `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);`, the `foreach` ends up calling the `IEnumerable<JToken>` iterator in the base class [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).  I.e. the following also works:

```
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);       
    foreach (var field in data)
    {
        // "field" happens to be of type JProperty
        var deserializedData = new DeserializedData
        {
            Label = field.Name,
            Content = field.Value.ToObject<string>()
        };
    }
```

Though I prefer the strongly typed version using `JObject` since more checking can be done at compile time.

Comment: This was awesome.....I like the strongly types version I will implement that..thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Children.htm) the JProperty's value contains the key, and the JProperty's children are the values. [source](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm)